# Basic rules for unit test case writing

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I've doubt writing unit test cases in my C# application. I've a class with 3 methods like

```
InsertEmp(int empid, string empname)
UpdateEmp(int empid, string empname)
SelectEmp(int empid)
```

My doubt is do we need to write unit test cases for all 3 methods? Because, when I write unit test cases for InsertEmp and UpdateEmp with some test data, always that test data is inserting (or updating) into my database.

Is that valid?

Comment: These look like they do three different things, so you need to test three different results, right?

Comment: Yes, three different results

Comment: So... three different set-ups, three different calls, and three different tests for success. So... three test cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, what are you testing?  If you're interacting with a physical database then you're not unit testing, you're integration testing.  Is the class which holds these methods tightly coupled with the database, or can it use a mock database?

If it can use a mock, provide that mock to the class when instantiating it and use that mock (or fake, or stub, there's [lots of subtle terminology](http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/14/TheLittleMocker.html)) to validate that the calls to these methods resulted in the expected interaction with the database.

If it can't use a mock and is tightly coupled with the database, then you can't unit test it in isolation from that database.  At that point you have two options:

1. De-couple it from the database implementation.
2. Decide if there's even logic worth unit testing.  If all these methods do internally is delegate insert/update/select commands to the database then they don't actually *do* anything that needs to be unit tested.  100% code coverage is nice, but what are you actually testing in this case?

If this class internally contains actual logic and isn't just a wrapper which directly delegates to a database component then it should be de-coupled from that component for testing purposes.  If it doesn't contain any actual logic, I still applaud the drive to 100% coverage but would put this pretty low on the priority list.

**Edit:** Another thing to consider is how this particular object fits into your overall business operations.  Ideally the bulk of the logic being tested is business logic, unrelated to these database commands.  So the bulk of your tests would be mocking *this* object to test the business logic, not testing this object directly.

In that case you may instead achieve code coverage of this object (tightly coupled or otherwise) by using it (instead of a mock) for integration tests of the business logic operations.  That is, instead of calling this object's methods directly you would call business logic operations which *themselves* call the methods on this object, effectively testing it.

Individual (atomic) business operations should be transactionally isolated anyway, so you should be able to run through the test and simply not commit the unit of work.  That would effectively test these, as integration tests against the database, without leaving side-effects.

Comment: One word of caution - rolling back a transaction can have unexpected consequences. For example, both SQL Server and Oracle will not release autoincrement/sequence values that were reserved by the transaction. Unless you clean these up later, your table could run out of values unexpectedly.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy: Potentially true, though hopefully tests aren't being executed against production servers...

Comment: agreed, but even non-prod servers can interrupt business when they encounter problems like this.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy: If a non-production server is interrupting business then I'd argue that the definition of "production" has been critically blurred and is a more underlying problem to be fixed, outside the scope of running automated tests.  For the example of a database, entirely dropping and re-building should be the push of a button (and in a test scenario should happen fairly often, perhaps as part of regularly scheduled automated integration tests).

Comment: Anyone executing tests would have their own instance. If you can set it up that way, awesome. Oracle is prohibitively expensive to do that. So you usually end up with databases for development, QA, etc. shared among multiple people or groups. If any one of them can blow away that database at the click of a button, that's a big deal. And yes, I realize that the whole point of a data abstraction layer is to fix this - but that's the whole point of the question. He doesn't have this abstraction layer, and many companies don't.